The problem with getting metadata using the yt-dlp library from YouTube
I have a problem using the yt-dlp library to download videos from YouTube
When getting the name of a video, sometimes the program gives out the wrong name, which does not exist at all
I use php for the query
Can you tell me how to make more stable queries to get the name of the video?
$metadata_command = "$yt_dlp_path --dump-json --verbose \"$user_url\"";
$metadata_output = [];
$metadata_return_var = 0;
exec($metadata_command, $metadata_output, $metadata_return_var);
if ($metadata_return_var !== 0) {
   echo "Metadata retrieval error: " . implode("\n", $metadata_output);
   throw new Exception('Metadata retrieval error video from YouTube');
}
if ($metadata_return_var === 0) {
    $metadata = json_decode(implode("\n", $metadata_output), true);
    if ($metadata === null) {
        throw new Exception('Error decoding JSON metadata.');
    }
    $video_title = $metadata['title'];
}

I tried to find mentions of a similar error on the Internet, but to no avail

--verbose just gives you non usable data that you have to implode, just remove that $metadata_command = "$yt_dlp_path --dump-json \"$user_url\"";. And just json_decode() the whole thing as is.
I don't see any reason why ['title'] would output bad data.

FYI: How do I format my posts? . This is unreadable as it is. Please take some care over your question, then you're more likely to get upvotes and good answers. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post, and remember to look at the preview before you save it, and make sure the code is actually formatted in a clear and readable way next time. Thanks
